# Flash video player issue in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-7, flashplayer-10

I am facing a strange issue in IE. I have a video player which is loaded as a popup. When it loads, flash player does not load anything. But when we right click on that section and click on "Play" it loads that player. Is there any fix for that.

I tried it in IE7 using Flash player 10 plugin.

To Elaborate.. The "Play" Button I am referring to is not inside the flash object. I am referring to the menu option which loads when you right click any flash object in browsers

Comment: Could you elaborate and show us some code? Preferably the code used to embed your swf in your html file.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any informations about your movie thus it's hard to tell you what's really going wrong.

Since you say "play" fixes your issue there's a good possiblity that you you use frame based code and didn't add a preloader or made a mistake with it. What you describe can happen when you jump to a frame that hasn't been loaded yet.

So if you spread code among several keyframes, always use a preloader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To elaborate.. "Play" button I am referring to the option in the menu. If you click on any flash object, we will get one menu which also has "Play" menu "Quality" etc. That is the menu I am taking about....

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the "play" that I talked about, too. What this menu entry does is starting/continueing the playback of the root movieclip (your main timeline). And if that solves the issue there's a good chance that it stopped without you wanting it to stop. Preloading issues are one of the reasons why this can happen but there also could be other reasons. If you know that preloading is not the issue, please provide us with a few more details about how your movie works and maybe an example that shows us where it happens.